# Unable to import Keras in Jupyter

Tags: python, keras, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So I set up my virtual lan with python 3 and jupyter (with pip). All works fine but if I try to import keras it will not work in jupyter and tells module not found. But if I execute the same file (python3 test.py) in the terminal it works fine.

```
which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter

which python3
/Users/niro273/Desktop/xcorp/bin/python3
```

If I do a `pip3 list` these are the results.

```
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (5.1.0)
jupyter-console (5.2.0)
jupyter-core (4.3.0)
Keras (2.0.8)
```

Note- I have installed jupyter (pip3 install jupyter) inside the virtual env too. So should I have to switch the juypter execution path ? Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Keras & Jupyter must be installed inside your virtual environment; then, you should start Jupyter after activating your virtual env (in which case `which jupyter` should point to a different location inside your virtual env):

```
$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
$ virtualenv /venv/foo
$ source /venv/foo/bin/activate
$ (foo) pip3 install jupyter
$ (foo) which jupyter
/venv/foo/bin/jupyter
$ (foo) pip3 install keras
$ (foo) jupyter notebook
```

There are certainly other ways (e.g. to [install a different kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda/47870277#47870277) in your main Jupyter installation pointing to the Python executable in your `foo` virtual environment), but I have found the above way to be quicker and more hassle-free, at least for Keras...

Comment: Tried this previously. The problem is although I install jupyter inside virtual lan the which jupyter results remains the same. Getting some thing like this "Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages" if I try to reinstall

Comment: OK, let's try the other way - can you please share the results of the command `jupyter kernelspec list`?

Comment: Oh , now figured out what happened. I have used this command to create the virtual env. "virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3". So this sites the global packages it seems. Thanks for guidance. :)

Answer (score 0):

***For Windows Users***

I had the same issue on Windows 10 @desertnaut's answer really helped.

**1 Activate the virtual environment.**

2 **Then `pip install jupyter`.**

3 **Then you are all set.**