# Jupyter Notebook in virtual environment doesn't see the virtual env packages

Tags: jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I'm trying to use a Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment.
I have created a new virtualenv `virtualenv ker12`
+ activate + installed a specific version of keras or any other library.

also as mentioned in [Using a virtualenv in an IPython notebook](http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/IPythonNotebookVirtualenvs) I did:

`pip install ipykernel`

and

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name`

when I run the notebook and write
`! which jupyter` the output is correct

> /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/bin/python

but when I try to import a library, for example `import keras` there is an error.

> ImportError: No module named keras

But from the other side when I write `pip freeze | grep Keras`
the output is:

> Keras==1.2.0

#### UPDATE 1:

this problem is not related to **Keras** it occurs with any other library (for example **pandas**)

If I print `os.path` the output is following:

> <'module 'posixpath' from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc>

From a "command line python" the os.path looks correct

> <'module 'posixpath' from '/Users/my_name/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>

#### UPDATE 2:

If I print `sys.path` from terminal and `jupyter` the output is also different:

**from terminal**

> /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python27.zip
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>   /Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/site-packages

**from JUPYTER**

> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
>   /Users/myname/.ipython `

Comment: Try `pip freeze -l` (list packages local to venv) — is Keras still there?

Comment: yes Keras appears for `pip freeze -l` also

Comment: try to use the full python/jupyter paths. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141764/jupyter-in-virtualenviroment-sys-path/47178282#47178282)

Comment: God, what a convoluted mess Python is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the solution is to open jupyter notebook with following command:

`~/virtualenv/my_venv_name/bin/jupyter-notebook`

Comment: to me it says: bash: /home/pal/virtualenv/env1/bin/jupyter-notebook: No such file or directory

Comment: did you check, that you indeed have this directory?

Comment: this didn't work for me, still giving me a ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score 7):

You should not install `ipykernel` - instead, you should go for a full Jupyter installation (`pip install jupyter`) inside your virtual environment. Additionally, be sure that you don't create your virtual environment with the `--system-site-packages` option.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939307/unable-to-import-keras-in-jupyter/45940330#45940330).

Comment: @deserhaut, also I added additional details [UPDATE], which may bring "more light" on the problem source.

Comment: @MichaelD can you share the results of a `jupyter kernelspec list` command, along with `which jupyter`, both when you are in "main" python and when in the virtual env?

Comment: without virtualenv there is an error 
> "Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
But in virtualenviroment (any of therm) the output is following:


`bash /Users/myname/Library/Jupyter/kernels/bash`
`ker12  /Users/myname/Library/Jupyter/kernels/ker12`
`phi  /Users/myname/Library/Jupyter/kernels/phi`
`python /Users /myname /virtualenv/ tf_new/ bin/../ share /jupyter/kernels / python2 `

@desertnaut