# jupyter in virtualenviroment sys.path

Tags: macos, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook

#### Jupyter in virtual enviroment doesn't succeed to load (import) libraries

I tried to print **sys.path** in virtual enviroment JUPYTER and TERMINAL and it looks different.

How it's possible to fix it?

If I print `sys.path` from terminal and `jupyter` the output is also different:

**from TERMINAL**

```
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python27.zip
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/myname/virtualenv/ker12/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

**from JUPYTER**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/Users/myname/.ipython
```

It looks, that in **sys.path** from JUPYTER doesn't include the paths to virtual environment...

Comment: Agree. The previous questions become too  long, here (I hope) I made more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the full path (to virtual env) to either the Jupyter notebook or the python bin, e.g.:

```
python /user/your_name/virtualenv/env1/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

or

```
 /user/your_name/virtualenv/env1/bin/python /user/your_name/virtualenv/env1/bin/jupyter-notebook
```