# PYspark SparkContext Error "error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext."

Tags: macos, apache-spark, terminal, pyspark

I know this question has been posted before, but I tried implementing the solutions, but none worked for me. I installed Spark for Jupyter Notebook
using this tutorial:

```
https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-mac-pyspark-
453f395f240b#.be80dcqat
```

Installed Latest Version of Apache Spark on the MAC

When I try to run the following code in Jupyter

```
wordcounts = sc.textFile('words.txt')
```

I get the following error:

```
name 'sc' is not defined
```

When I try adding the Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc =SparkContext()
```

getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling 
None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils
at
org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.
getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
```

Added the path in bash:

```
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

#For python 3, You have to add the line below or you will get an error
# export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: How do you set spark_path? could you provide the full url?

Comment: I added the following to the bash

export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

#For python 3, You have to add the line below or you will get an error
# export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'

Comment: which version of java do you have? Can you type: java -version   ,and share the result?

Comment: `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"` is a really crappy solution, and it should be avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda/47870277#47870277

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Version is 9

Answer (score 0):

**These steps solve my problem [ pyspark with jupyter notebook local setup for window os ]**

Error for me in *jupyter notebook*

[image]

---

1. download and install java8 :  https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows
2. download spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7 : https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

- Unpack the .tgz file using 7zip or other tool
- put it like C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7

**Note** : we will use this path for environment variables

3. download winutils.exe : https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin

- put it into C:\Hadoop\bin location

4. download and install python on window : https://www.python.org/downloads/
5. **Add environment variables:**

In the Settings window, under Related Settings, click Advanced system settings.
On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables. Click New to create a new environment variable.
Click Edit to modify an existing environment variable.

5.1. User variable:

- JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8
- PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin
- HADOOP_HOME : C:\Hadoop
- PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON : jupyter
- PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS : notebook
- PYSPARK_PYTHON : xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
- SPARK_HOME : C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
- SPARK_LOCAL_IP : localhost

5.2. system variables:

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin
- C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
- C:\Hadoop\bin

**Testing:**

1. open cmd and run >> java -version

   C:\Users\xxxxxxx>java -version

it should return like

```
java version "1.8.0_371"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_371-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.371-b11, mixed mode)
```

2. In cmd run
   `C:\Users\xxxxxxx>pyspark`

this command redirect you at *http://localhost:8890/tree*

3. create new notebook and write below code and run

   import findspark
   findspark.init()

   import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
   spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

   df = spark.sql('''select 'spark' as India ''')
   df.show()

**After following above steps**

[image]

**------------- Note ------------------**

if all set and you still showing error "Using Spark's default log4j ERROR SparkContext ....... " then try below steps:

1. try to close cmd window and reopen it and try to execute >>pyspark command in cmd again
2. try to restart your system and reopen cmd and try to re run >>pyspark command again
3. check java version, some time java latest version raise error with pyspark try with jdk-1.8 and spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7, seems like jdk-1.8 and spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7 is working for me.