# PySpark install error

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have followed instructions from various blogs posts including [this](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-231c45677de0), [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/apache-spark-python), [this](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f) and [this](https://github.com/KristianHolsheimer/pyspark-setup-guide#spark-install) to install pyspark on my laptop. However when I try to use pyspark from terminal or jupyter notebook I keep getting following error.

I have installed all the necessary software as shown at the bottom of the question.

I have added the following to my `.bashrc`

```
function sjupyter_init()
{
#Set anaconda3 as python
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

#Spark path (based on your computer)
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:/home/khurram/anaconda3/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
}
```

I execute `sjupyter_init` followed by `jupyter notebook` from terminal to launch jupyter notebooks with pyspark.

In a notebook I execute the following without error

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/opt/spark')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

But when I execute below line

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
```

It results in this error message

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/01/20 17:10:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/home/khurram/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1428, in __call__
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "/home/khurram/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:546)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-0he7: linux-0he7: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:941)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-0he7: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
        ... 23 more
```

My OS details are

**OS:**

```
OpenSuse Leap 42.2 64-bit
```

**Java:**

```
    khurram@linux-0he7:~> java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
```

**Scala**

```
    khurram@linux-0he7:~> scala -version
    Scala code runner version 2.12.4 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

**Hadoop 3.0**

```
khurram@linux-0he7:~> echo $HADOOP_HOME
/opt/hadoop
```

**Py4J**

```
khurram@linux-0he7:~> pip show py4j
Name: py4j
Version: 0.10.6
Summary: Enables Python programs to dynamically access arbitrary Java objects
Home-page: https://www.py4j.org/
Author: Barthelemy Dagenais
Author-email: barthelemy@infobart.com
License: BSD License
Location: /home/khurram/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
khurram@linux-0he7:~>
```

I have executed `chmod 777` for `hadoop` and `spark` directories.

```
khurram@linux-0he7:~> ls -al /opt/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root   96 Jan 19 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root  222 Jan 20 14:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root   18 Jan 19 20:22 hadoop -> /opt/hadoop-3.0.0/
drwxrwxrwx 1 khurram users 126 Dec  8 19:42 hadoop-3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root    root   30 Jan 19 19:40 spark -> /opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
drwxrwxrwx 1 khurram users 150 Jan 19 19:33 spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
khurram@linux-0he7:~>
```

**Contents of hosts file**

```
khurram@linux-0he7:> cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost

# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0         ipv6-localnet

ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts
```

Comment: @user8371915 add contents of  ```/etc/hosts``` to OP. Based on the question you mentioned shall I add ```linux-0he7``` to hosts file?

Comment: Exactly - `127.0.0.1       linux-0he7`

Comment: @user8371915 Your suggestion has solved the problem. Can you please put that in the answer so that I can upvote you

Comment: By the way, `spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7` download included Hadoop... You did not need to download Hadoop separately, or if you did, you needed version 2.7

Comment: On a more general level, setting `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"` is a really bad practice; for the proper way of setting Jupyter to work with pyspark, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda/47870277#47870277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`UnknownHostException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) is

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

and it is thrown at the bottom of your stack trace:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-0he7: Name or service not known

Looking at your prompt shell `linux-0he7` so I assume you're using local mode. This means that your `/etc/hosts` doesn't include `linux-0he7`.

Adding

```
127.0.0.1    linux-0he7
```

to `/etc/hosts` should resolve the problem.

You can also use `spark.driver.bindAddress` and `spark.driver.host` to use specific host IP for the driver.

Independent of the exception Hadoop 3.0.0 is not supported yet. I would recommend using 2.x for the time being.

Comment: /etc/hosts worked on my cloud. spark.driver.bindAddress did not work