# How to include external Spark library while using PySpark in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to run the following PySpark-Kafka streaming [example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py) in a Jupyter Notebook. Here is the first part of the code I am using in my notebook:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='local[*]',appName="PySpark streaming")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

topic = "my-topic"
brokers = "localhost:9092"
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
```

If I run the cell, I receive the following error/description:

```
Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
 spark-submit command as

$ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.3.0 ...

2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.3.0.
Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

$ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...
```

My questions are: how can I pass the --jars or --package argument to Jupyter Notebook? Or, can I download this package and link it permanently to Python/Jupyter (maybe via an export in the .bashrc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways of doing so, corresponding roughly to the two options suggested in the error message:

The **first way** is to update accordingly your respective Jupyter kernel (if you are not already using Jupyter kernels, you should - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824131/configuring-spark-to-work-with-jupyter-notebook-and-anaconda/47870277#47870277) for the detailed generalities of using kernels in Jupyter for Pyspark).

More specifically, you should update your respective `kernel.json` configuration file for Pyspark with the following entry under `env` (if you use something else than `--master local`, modify accordingly):

```
"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.3.0 pyspark-shell"
```

The **second way** is to put the following entry in your `spark-defaults.conf` file:

```
spark.jars.packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.3.0
```

In both cases, you don't need to download anything manually - the first time you run Pyspark with the updated configuration, the necessary files will be downloaded and put in the appropriate directories.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I can config to run PySpark (verison with scala 2.12 Spark 3.2.1) Structure Streaming with Kafka on jupyter lab

First,I download 5 jars files and I put them in the folder /jars under my current project folder (just for local run I think):

- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar
- kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar
- spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.2.1.jar
- commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar
- spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar

The value of config spark.jars look like this  "<path-to-jar/test1.jar>,<path-to-jar/test2.jar>"

This is the actual code:

```py
spark_jars =  ("{},{},{},{},{}".format(os.getcwd() + "/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar",  
                                      os.getcwd() + "/jars/kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar", 
                                      os.getcwd() + "/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.12-3.2.1.jar", 
                                      os.getcwd() + "/jars/commons-pool2-2.8.0.jar",  
                                      os.getcwd() + "/jars/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar"))


spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", spark_jars).appName("Structured_Redpanda_WordCount").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
```